# How are FaaS / Serverless Architectures actually implemented at Cloud Providers

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, serverless-architecture

How are the different [FaaS or Serverless Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html) offerings of the major cloud providers effectively implemented in terms of backend and infrastructure?

- **AWS Lambda**: Java, Node.js, C#, Python, binaries
- **Azure Functions**: JavaScript, C#, Python, PHP, Bash, Batch, PowerShell
- **Google Cloud Functions**: JavaScript

Google Cloud Functions seems to be based on a managed Node.js environment according to here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview which seems to be different and a limiting factor.

AWS and Azure support a multitude of different runtimes which may look like an ideal docker use case? At least the underlying logical core concept is very close to process isolation/containerization respectively scaling of these which would lead us to Kubernetes/Mesos? It wouldn't be very efficient to invent custom solutions nowadays, wouldn't it?

Does anyone know what is at work behind the scenes?

Comment: This type of question will only get you speculation, discussion, and opinion. Off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: not sure it belongs here, has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 1):

I had a discussion with an AWS Engineer a while back and he confirmed my suspicion that AWS Lambda is run's on top of docker. Can't comment on azure or google's infrastructure though...